# Number of pixels Elevation - Aspect - Slope

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, elevation, slope

I have a DEM, resampled at 100 x 100 and clip by mask with a polygon.

Unique values report give me Total pixel count: 733810 with NODATA pixel count: 427098.

Aspect and Slope map give me the same number of pixels but NODATA pixel count: 423251.

My question is why when i clip by extent or clip by mask , area around my raster has NODATA values? How can i get rid of these so have same amount of pixels to every parameter? The problem doesnt solves if i reclassify them with zero because i need to export them to csv and analyze them and need exactly same number of pixels.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A raster has to be rectangular, that is why you get no data values when you clip with a irregular polygon. Maybe slope and aspect cant be calculated at the border to no data. Can you calculate them first then clip?

Comment: This worked for parametres that arise from DEM but when im creating distance to rivers map with same layer extent, same CRS, same spatial resolution, the 2 layers dont stack exactly one to another and have more NODATA pixels. Any idea ?